# How to group correctly when trying to select max value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this query currently:

```html
SELECT [Description]  
   ,[Inspection_No]
   ,[InspectionSpecification_No]
   ,[Description]
   ,[Class]      
   ,[Notes]     
   ,[InspectionDate]               
   ,[Job]     
   ,[Lot]         
   ,[Result]         
   ,[CreateDate]          
   ,[SampleNumber]
  FROM 
   (SELECT     
     [Inspection_No]
    ,[InspectionSpecification_No]
    ,[Description]
    ,[Class]      
    ,[Notes]     
    ,[InspectionDate]               
    ,[Job]     
    ,[Lot]         
    ,[Result]         
    ,[CreateDate]          
    ,[SampleNumber]
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition BY [Lot], [Description], [SampleNumber]
    ORDER BY [InspectionDate] DESC) rn

 FROM      [A].[dbo].[PT_Inspection]) tmp

 WHERE     rn = 1 AND [Lot] IS NOT NULL AND ([InspectionDate] > DATEADD(DAY, - 600, GETDATE())) and [Lot] = @LotNumber and [Job] is not null and Job != ''
```

Which is working great. It brings in all the data I need. I would like to limit this data to just the highest [SampleNumber] for each [Description]. I've been trying to insert it all into a temp table, but I just can't seem to figure out how. If I were to manage to get it all into a temptable and then call upon that, how would I return all columns of data for only the highest [SampleNumber] for each [Description]. I'm still learning SQL and new to StackOverflow, so please let me know if I need to include any further information.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the highest sample number for each description, then just change the partitioning/ordering clause in `row_number()`:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Description]
                   ORDER BY [SampleNumber] DESC, [InspectionDate] DESC
                  ) rn
```

Comment: Should this be `PARTITION BY [Description]`and not `PARTITION BY [Lot], [Description]` otherwise it is not the max value for description but for lot then description

Comment: @PhilipPryde . . . That sounds like a more reasonable interpretation of the question.

Comment: your thinking is definitely correct. I'm not sure why, but when I only partitioned by [Description], it came back with no results. But when I partitioned by [Lot] and [Description], and then ordered by [SampleNumber] and [InspectionDate] the results came back exactly as I had hoped. Thanks for helping with this!!